# Stokes problem without Dirichlet boundary Condition (only Neumann boundary condition).

Tags: functional-analysis, finite-element-method

The weak formulation of the following Stokes-like problem **without Dirichlet boundary conditions** is well posed?

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ a bounded domain.

**The weak problem is:** Find $u\in H^1(\Omega)^2$ and $p\in L^2(\Omega)$ such that

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\displaystyle\int_\Omega\nabla u:\nabla\,dx+\int_\Omega u\cdot v\,dx-\int_\Omega p\,div(v)=\int_\Omega f\cdot v\,dx+\int_{\partial\Omega}g\cdot v\,dx\quad\textrm{ for all }v\in H^1(\Omega)^2
\\
\displaystyle-\int_\Omega q\,div(u)=0\quad\textrm{ for all }q\in L^2(\Omega)
\end{array}\right.$$

**The strong problem is:**

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rl}-\Delta u+u+\nabla p =f&\textrm{ in }\Omega
\\
div(u)=0&\textrm{ in }\Omega
\\
(\nabla u-p\,I)n=g&\textrm{ on }\partial\Omega
\end{array}\right.$$

Note that this problem **don't has Dirichlet boundary condition** (don't has conditions like $u=g_D$ on $\partial\Omega$) and **only has Neumann boundary condition** (the condition $(\nabla u-p\,I)n=g$ on $\partial\Omega$)

Comment: Where do you see any problems when compared to the standard proof with Dirichlet boundary conditions? inf-sup theory should work here as well.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand much of your "weak formulation". What e.g. is $\,\int_\Omega\nabla u:\nabla\,dx$ ?